# Any progress on the Firoozbakht Conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p_n$ be the n-th prime. The [Firoozbakht Conjecture](http://www.primepuzzles.net/conjectures/conj_030.htm) is a lesser known conjecture in the theory of primes but it has important consequences. It states that

$$
p_n^{\frac{1}{n}} > p_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n+1}}
$$

This truth of this immediately imply the Cramer's conjecture. In fact Firoozbakht conjecture is slightly better than the Cramer's conjecture in the sense that it would imply that

$$p_{n+1} - p_n < \ln^2p_n - \ln p_n.$$

Notice that while Firoozbakht Conjecture will automatically imply the Cramer conjecture, it will also disprove the [Cramer-Granville Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cramer-GranvilleConjecture.html).

What has been the progress in this conjecture? Using computer calculation the conjecture has been verified, for all n upto 1.69x$10^{16}.$

Comment: I suppose any progress made on a conjecture of such importance would be easily located by google?

Comment: Why would it disprove the Cramer-Granville conjecture?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.05

Comment: +1 to both previous comments. I agree with Gerhard in the sense that a superficial check suggests that this conjecture might strengthen Cramer-Granville rather than disprove it. Anyway, I tend to suggest that you indeed use Google, or contact the author of the conjecture (http://www.ui.ac.ir/websofts/ws2/en_ws2.php?id=10&lang=e).

Comment: @ Gerhard, Cramer-Granville conjecture says that the $O$ constant is greater than 1 (explained in the answer below by Quid) where as the Firoozbakht's Conjecture says it is 1. So both Firoozbakht's conjecture and Cramer-Granville conjecture cannot be simultaneously true.

Comment: Thank you Neel.  For some reason the conjecture appeared to me as saying that the constant M had to be less than 1.  Gerhard ""Now Where Are My Glasses" Paseman, 2012.03.06

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It did not quite occur to me that the one has to read that conjecture not literally as "an inequality holds" but as "an inequality holds, and stronger inequalities don't". 

Comment: Given the pointless discussion user 'humble' continues posting more and more comments as new answers, I vote to close as "no longer relevant".

Comment: I believe the proper reaction is to flag humble’s “answers” as spam, which I just did.

Comment: Meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1326/discussion-of-firoozbakht-conjecture/

Comment: The conjecture is true up to $4\cdot10^{18}.$ (I expect it's eventually false.)

Comment: At the moment it is not quite clear whether this applies to this statement as well but for general information there could be a problem with naming this Cramér-Granville see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114399/consequences-of-legendres-conjecture/122939#122939

Comment: As of 2017, the conjecture is true for all primes up to $10^{19}$, based on new data at [T.R.Nicely's prime gaps website](http://trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html) combined with the sufficient condition in Theorem 3 of [arXiv:1506.03042](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03042).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Significantly rewritten, yet the main message stays the same.*

It is quite likely that this conjecture is *false* yet no counter example was found so far.

The reason why this  seems likely is that there seems to be no supporting evidence for this conjecture beyond numerics.

*And*, there are investigations base on quite natural random models of the primes that contradict it. What is commonly known as Cramér's conjecture, that is that maximal gaps between consecutive primes are of sizes at most $(\log p_n)^2$ (up to lower order terms) does not contradict this conjecture, and one might even think it supports it.
However, on the one hand it is not quite clear Cramér even conjectured this in precisely this form; he conjectured gaps are $O((\log p_n)^2)$ and somehow implied that about  $(\log p_n)^2$ might be true. On the other hand, and more importantly, Granville note that a finer investigations of Cramér's reasoning rather suggests maximal gaps of size $2 e^{-\gamma} (\log p_n)^2$ (up to lower order terms). And if this were true it would contradict the conjecture mentioned in OP (this is what is referred to in OP as Cramér-Granville conjecture).

It should however be noted that Granville did *not* conjecture that the gaps are of this size, yet pointed out what taking an additional aspect into account would mean for Cramér's reasoning. For Granville on this matter on MO see [Consequences of Legendre's conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114399/consequences-of-legendres-conjecture/122939#122939)

For details on Granville's arguments see for example 
http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/chance_news/for_chance_news/Riemann/cramer.pdf