# What is the minimal range $[f(n),g(n)]$ that contains a prime number for every integer $n>0$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

**I know the following:**

- Proven: There is a prime number between $n$ and $2n$ for every integer $n>0$.
- Conjectured: There is a prime number between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ for every integer $n>0$.

**My questions are:**

1. Is the above correct?
2. Has this been conjectured or refuted:

   There is a prime number between $n^2$ and $n(n+1)$ for every integer $n>0$ ?
3. What is the minimal range $[f(n),g(n)]$ proven to contain a prime number for every $n>0$?

**UPDATE:**

The term 'minimal' is somewhat confusing in this case, since obviously, the difference between $n$ and $2n$ is in fact smaller than the difference between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

So to refine my question - 'minimal range' refers to the **ratio** between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, and not to the difference between them. In other words $Min[g(n)/f(n)]$ instead of $Min[g(n)-f(n)]$.

Comment: I think it is more clear if you fix $f$ to be the identity, $f(n)=n$ (besides, taking $f(n)=g(n)=p_n$ would somehow trivialize the question)

Comment: It will not describe my question properly if I do so. Please note that I'm asking if there is a prime number between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$. How can $f(n)$ be $n$ in this case?

Comment: Then maybe your problem is : the function $f$ being ${\it given}$, ${\it find}$ the smallest function $g\ge f$ such that there is a prime in the interval? I was just saying that if we can choose both $f$ and $g$ there is the trivial answer above.

Comment: @Pietro Majer: Oh, I understand now, you mean $f(n)=P_{n}$ and $g(n)=P_{n+1}$?

Comment: Actually I really meant $f(n)=g(n)=p_n$.

Comment: @Pietro Majer, thanks... either way, what I meant is a range between two "finitely defined" functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$. Can you define $P_n$ in a finite "amount of paper"?

Comment: It is easy to define $P_n$ with a few symbols: $P_n$ is the $n$-th prime number.

Comment: @GH from MO: Well I kinda meant mathematical symbols (though I'm not sure how to express this meaning in a "mathematical notion").

Comment: @barak: The "$n$-th prime number" has a short formal definition within set theory (ZFC), it is a translation of the usual definition "in words". In fact any recursive function can be represented by a first order formula within Peano arithmetic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Baker-Harman-Pintz (2000) proved that for every sufficiently large $n$ the interval $[n-n^{0.525},n]$ contains a prime number. Schoenfeld (1976) proved that if the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then the term $n^{0.525}$ in the previous statement can be replaced by $\sqrt{n}\log^2 n$. For a very recent strengthening of this result, see this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6417). This is still probably far from the truth, e.g. Cramér (1937) made the conjecture based on a probabilistic model, that the term $n^{0.525}$ above can be replaced by a certain constant times $\log^2 n$.

Comment: Strangely I only got notified of your answer when it was already almost 15 mins old; so mine was almost done and I thus posted it and leave it, also as the symmetric difference is  nonempty. And, thanks for bringing that preprint to my attention.

Comment: @quid: Thanks for the feedback and your response as well!

Comment: So my question to both you and @quid: your answers make the conjecture of a prime number between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ sound a little redundant (i.e., not so important to prove), as there is a "tighter bound" conjecture. Am I correct?

Comment: @barakmanos yes in my opinion this conjecture is almost purely relevant for historical reasons (Legendre was a pioneer in that field an the conjecture dates from around 1800 where these questions were much less understood), see my comments on  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114399/consequences-of-legendres-conjecture

Comment: @quid: Thanks, interesting post (including the notion about that guy who claims he did not make a specific conjecture, and it's also wrong on Wikipedia)... BTW, I would not vote to close it (as you did)...

Comment: @barak: Having a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ is much the same as having a prime in $[n-n^{1/2},n]$. The result of Baker-Harman-Pintz is somewhat weaker, because the exponent there is 0.525 instead of 1/2. The (unproven) Riemann Hypothesis almost implies the exponent 1/2, but as things stand today, we need an extra factor of $\log n$ there. More optimistic conjectures reduce the gap dramatically, cf. my response.

Comment: @barakmanos well in the end I came around to answer it rather then close it but point taken. Yes, Granville showing up to clarify some points regarding conjectures was interesting. I think it  was really helpful this information came up here.

Comment: Quid, can you please have a look at the comment above, made by @GH from MO? It suggests that the 'prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$' conjecture actually puts a **tighter bound** than the current bound inferred by the Baker-Harman-Pintz conjecture. So doesn't this make the former conjecture still "relevant"?

Comment: @quid, can you please have a look at the comment above?

Comment: @barakmanos yes of course it is tighter than what is *known* (otherwise I would not have answered that it is true that this is a conjecture as you said). What I mean is that the conjecture now seems a bit arbitrary as a lot stronger things *should* be true and these days one would rather not phrase a conjecture like this to begin with. Or put differently the conjecture got superseeded by other stronger/better conjectures, so it is not that relevant anymore.

Comment: @quid, sorry but I'm not sure I understand. First you say that there is a better approximation than the range $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, so it is interesting only due to historical reasons. But then you say that the result of Baker-Harman-Pintz is actually weaker (well, `GH from MO` says that, but you appear to agree with it). Can you please clarify?

Comment: @barakmanos also I always said it was not know, please, see that I said if one can *improve* on BHP then it would follow. If somebody conjectures something is at most size 100, and then somebody else conjectures it is actually size at most 15 and now most everybody agrees this 15 should be alright then the original conjecture of at most 100 is not really relevant anymore, even if 105 is the best anybody can prove at the moment. At least this is what I think and meant. Of course if somebody could improve the result from 105 to 100 this *would be relevant*. [...]

Comment: But then also to improve it to 90 would be relevant and so on, so that 100 does not really have any special role (intrinsic to the mathematics at hand), except for historical reasons. This is somehow the situation here, one knows something for .525, for .5 and something extra one would get the conjecture, but actually it should also be true for .4, for .0001 for everything positive. Sure, proving .5 would be relevant but it does not seem to have any very special role. I hope this clears up what I meant. If you want to continue perhaps comment on my answer so that GH does not get notified.

Comment: @barak: Let me clarify and supplement quid's remarks. For $c>0$ let $L(c)$ denote the statement that "if $n$ is sufficiently large then there is always a prime between $n-n^c$ and $n$". Note that decreasing $c$ makes $L(c)$ stronger, and $L(1/2)$ is essentially the same as Legendre's conjecture. Currently $L(0.525)$ is known, the Riemann Hypothesis implies $L(c)$ for any $c>1/2$, while probably $L(c)$ is true for any $c>0$.

Comment: OK, @GH from MO,quid: So the 'prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$' conjecture implies $L(1/2)$ which implies $L(0.525)$, is that correct? Now, $L(0.525)$ has been proven, but $L(1/2)$ hasn't been proven, is that correct? If yes, doesn't that mean that the unproven 'prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$' conjecture is still interesting **not only for historical reasons**?

Comment: @barak: Legendre's conjecture implies a slightly weaker variant of $L(1/2)$: there is a prime in $[n-5\sqrt{n},n]$. On the other hand, $L(1/2)$ implies Legendre's conjecture. It is subjective what is interesting and for what reasons. quid tried to say, and I agree with him, that the specific intervals $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ are not too interesting in this problem. We don't really distinguish between the following intervals: $[n-\sqrt{n},n]$, $[n-100\sqrt{n},n]$, $[n-\sqrt{n}\log^{29} n,n]$, $[n-n^{1/2+o(1)},n]$. They are much the same, and they are on the edge what the Riemann Hypothesis can handle.

Comment: Probably the probabilistic model does not give the correct answer when dealing with primes in short intervals. Maier's matrix method shows that on a scale up to a power of $\log x$ the distribution of primes is much more irregular than what probability would predict.

Comment: @Jan-Christoph: I agree, but let us also emphasize that it has been very difficult to find larger than average gaps between primes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds).

Answer (score 6):

Yes what you say is correct.

For the minimal range known, it is know by results of Baker, Harman, Pintz that $[x, x + x^{0.525}]$ contains a prime for all sufficiently large $x$, as a consequence of this, but in fact already of earlier results, it is known that there is a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$ for all sufficiently large $n$. If one could replace $0.525$ by $0.5$ this would essentially yield the conjecture you mentioned, known as Legendre's conjecture.

This also immediately yields, but really for this the Prime Number Theorem suffices, that the ratio of your $g(n)/f(n)$ can be taken to tend to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. And, the difference, in a suitable sense, is rather the better notion to consider here.

It is conjetured that $[x, x + f(x)]$ contains a prime for each $x$ where $f$ is some  $O( (\log x)^2)$; the key-word here is Cramér's conjecture, which is still slightly more precise but it is not quite clear what exactly should be conjectured. But the $O( (\log x)^2)$ is likely about alright.

In the converse direction it is known (due to Rankin) that there are infinitely many $n$ such that the gap between $n$ and $n+1$ prime is of size

$$c \frac{(\log n) (\log \log n)(\log \log \log \log n)}{ (\log \log \log n)^2} $$
for a positive $c$.