# Published articles in journals about the Firoozbakht's conjecture, whose main goal or focus is the study of this conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures

I would like to know what articles are in the literature about the known as Firoozbakht's conjecture, see the Wikipedia [*Firoozbakht's conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture).

> **Question.** What articles have been published in journals 
>   whose main goal is the study of Firoozbakht's conjecture? **Many thanks.**

I'm interested to know it, since I'm not a professor, what articles were published in journals, these don't merely mentioning the conjecture: I am asking thus about articles dedicated to the study of the Firoozbakht's conjecture as a remarkable or the main goal of the article, or the studied subject of the articles that I evoke is very closely-related to the Firoozbakht's conjecture.

I know thus the following reference as an answer of my Question, this

Alexei Kourbatov, *Upper Bounds for Prime Gaps
Related to Firoozbakht’s Conjecture*, Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. **18** (2015), Article 15.11.2.

Comment: From the first paragraph of the linked Wikipedia encyclopedia I deduce that it is an open conjecture about primes ​​for more of $\approx$37 years.

Comment: Google Scholar returns many [relevant papers](https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Firoozbakht+conjecture&btnG=)

Comment: If you've an answer add it, and it will be upvoted in the same way that if other person asks about a subject of the fields that you're working you can upvote an useful answer @CarloBeenakker  It's how the site works. References from journals or books (after that it is standard science) are very important, because it isn't an opinion of a group or specific person, it is science that share the community of scientifics, and that one can invoke to accept the solution of an issue or to make more progress. I hope you don't see my words are wrongs or rude. I don't accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Carlo has been an active contributor to this site for eight years, 142929, I think he knows how the site works. Do you know how Math Reviews works? or Zentralblatt? Do you have access to a library?

Comment: Yes, I have access to a library but I have not searched for information using telematic tools (the databases that you're saying). If I was rude in my previous comment, I'm sorry. But when I have edited my question/post, what I expected is an answer to my question @GerryMyerson

Comment: I would encourage you to use the search tools that are available nowadays. There is something satisfying about doing your own work, instead of asking others to do it for you. As for what you expect, I'm afraid you'll have to take what you can get.

Comment: This question is almost a duplicate of [another MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/90327).

Comment: With all respect to you @TimothyChow , the question of your link is a question asked 7 years ago, it is closed as no longer relevant and isn't a reference request about the published articles in journals about the Firoozbakht's conjecture. I am not asking about the progress to discuss it.

Comment: And I am not interested in your comment @TimothyChow , delete it because isn't the feedback that I was looking in this site when I am asking serious questions about mathematics.

Comment: You seem to be in the habit of making demands on people. I am not going to comply with your demand that I delete Timothy's comment, because it was made in good faith and intended to be helpful (it is not a call to close as duplicate), and indeed is potentially useful. (Moreover, you seem not to have understood why the linked question was closed as "no longer relevant".) I am complying with your demand to reply because your flag doesn't offer the option of replying privately. As noted by Gerry, you have exhibited little research effort, making the question not a very good one.

Comment: Advice: avoid the imperative mode when trying to get people to help you, and make a good attempt to answer your own question beforehand, rather than demand that distinguished mathematicians do your work for you (as Carlo Beenakker has done).

Comment: I had the idea to ask about this conjecture with good faith, two times this week. You and your colleagues can be proud of me for this fact, the presence of the conjecture in MO: is science. I feel if I was rude to the user who answered the question. I don't have enough skills and knowledges to bring/know here all the references in the literature about this conjecture. I haven't searched in math databases for over 10 years. Yesterday merely to give back books on my library I need more than sixteen kilometers walking @ToddTrimble ,I don't make demands of everything, not even hitchhiking

Comment: Hm, you may need to look up what "imperative" means. When you tell someone to add an answer, or to delete a comment, or when you demand a moderator reply, without ever using the magic word "please": those are imperatives. Again, I would strongly urge you to avoid writing in that mode. I'll also say that people leave comments sometimes for readers in general, and not only for you -- you can think of your question as not really owned by you, but now part of the public commons. Thus, even if you don't consider Timothy Chow's comment useful to you personally, others might find it useful.

Comment: Well then, imperatively or not, I'm sorry please. My intention and goal with my posts asking about the Firoozbakht's conjecture was to learn (in my circumstances) and ask about if is interesting to combine it with other prime conjectures as I did in MO question *341821*: *What relationships are there between the Firoozbakht's conjecture and the abc conjecture?* that I've deleted as owner, sadly. I sadly I am not the author of this Firoozbakht's conjecture. I can be the author of mediocre posts in which I demand attention from others in helping to explore the mathematical science @ToddTrimble

Comment: I hope I don't disturb/bother you with this comment @TimothyChow , but I was wrong with you in my previous comments and I want to say *I'm sorry for my rude response to your feedback.* Isn't required a response of this comment and best week.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Verification of the Firoozbakht conjecture for primes up to four quintillion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01744)

[On the Firoozbakht's conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08917)

[Some consequences of the Firoozbakht's conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03496)

[Prime gaps and the Firoozbakht Conjecture](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40863-018-0113-0)

[Verifying the Firoozbakht, Nicholson, and Farhadian conjectures up to the 81st maximal prime gap](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00499)

[Revisiting Generalized Bertand's Postulate and Prime Gaps](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09891)

[On the distribution of maximal gaps between primes in residue classes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03340)

Comment: Many thanks for this excellent answer.